# ARIA : how to focus on every element I want?

Tags: html, focus, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm trying to learn accessibility with WAI-ARIA and all this kind of stuff but I'm really lost, I went for the official documentations on W3C and MDN but couldn't have precise idea about how to proceed.

This is my Website (don't mind top left blue and red stuff, it's NVDA focusing).
[image: screen capture of the developer's website]

I don't know yet if I'm on the right track, how to proceed and if it's good way or not but I would like, when entering in document, that when I press TAB key, it focuses on the  tag and when I press TAB again, it goes down into the header, so here the navbrand, then navmenu and when I press TAB again while on navmenu, that it goes down into it. In fact, I would like a kind of tabulation navigation that will be able to focus on "every" important division (here : header, main, footer, each section of main, each card of section, each text of each card, etc...)

For know, to give you a visual hint of what's happening, when I'm at the document's root and that I press TAB key, it will directly go at first link of the navigation.

Could someone light my way ? Am I planning things good or not ? If yes, how to proceed ? (Even if not good, how to proceed ?)

**Thanks a lot for your time.**

N.B.: I've hearded that it's bad thing to use tab-index > 0 and tried tab-index = 0 and even -1 and it doesn't work and I don't know if it's bad practice or not because may corrupt the DOM order or I don't know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you need is a good primer on keyboard accessibility.

The correct behavior for tabbing is to move focus through the ***interactive portions of the webpage*** (e.g. buttons, links, form inputs, etc.).

Tabbing generally does not and should not set focus on non-interactive sectioning elements (e.g. header, main, footer, nav, etc.) or on static content, like paragraphs, lists, divs, spans, etc.

If you want to improve accessibility of navigation on your page, then you may want to consider the following:

- Using HTML5 elements that already have [implicit ARIA roles](https://www.a11yproject.com/posts/2013-01-14-aria-landmark-roles/#html5-implicit-mappings-of-landmark-roles) mapped, where possible
- Implementing [landmark roles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques#landmark_roles) where implicit roles are not appropriate
- Implementing [skip links](https://webaim.org/techniques/skipnav/) so that repetitive navigation can be bypassed
- Ensure that your [focus indicator](https://www.deque.com/blog/give-site-focus-tips-designing-usable-focus-indicators/) is easily visible and not hidden by CSS

`tabindex` should typically be avoided unless you really know what you're doing and have a very good reason for using it. Generally, the reading order should follow the visual ordering of the page, which should also follow the DOM ordering.

Additional Resources:

- [Keyboard Navigation - WebAIM](https://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/)
- [Understanding Focus Order - WCAG 2.1](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/focus-order.html)
- [WAI-ARIA Design Patterns and Widgets](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#aria_ex)
- [ARIA Features Not Currently Available in HTML5](https://www.tpgi.com/aria-in-html-there-goes-the-neighborhood/#html5na)

Comment: So, okay, tab is for interactive content, got it and in my case it works fine.
But I mean... when does the screen reader will read the non interactive content of the page ? Can the user freely go "deeper" in the div and go "upper" in the hierarchy as he wants ? Because when I refresh my page, all is ok as for the interactive content but the screen reader won't read anything of the page by itself so what is the exact process in reading the page ?

Comment: @BriceJoosten You might find this helpful:
https://dequeuniversity.com/screenreaders/nvda-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a look and try to get better knowledge about how a screen reader proceeds because for now, it's still a bit blurry in my mind...

Comment: It does take some practice, and you'll almost certainly find some settings within NVDA that you'll want to change. Many people find that it's easier when starting out to slow down the speech and change out the default voice for a better one.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that in NVDA. Fortunately, it didn't take me much time to find where settings are and how to start stop quickly, remap start/stop voice for easier and faster enabling/disabling voice. For the speed I may have put something like 40/45 out of 100. Still learning it though.

Comment: It's great that you're doing this. Many devs won't bother to spend the time. Thank you for   helping to make the world a little more accessible.

Comment: No problem, I'm a junior dev that just graduated and in my formation we've been spoken about accessibility literally only one time but no true lesson about it. I want to try to make the same UX regardless support, people, etc and for some reason I've met accessibility stuff and so I tried NVDA to imagine how a blind user would use my website. Testing NVDA on many common websites, eyes closed, I've noticed how it's a real mess, you can't figure out what's happening, where you are on the page etc, what is element... So I think a true fix for these issues is to design accessibility-first.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you use semantic html (meaning you use a `<table>` element when you have a table, a `<ul>` when you have a list, an `<h2>` when you have a heading, etc), then you should not need any ARIA attributes.  In fact, [the first rule of ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#rule1) is to not use ARIA.

ARIA should only be used to fill in gaps where either semantic html is not available or there's a reason you can't use semantic html (such as for styling purposes, you have to use a `<div>` with CSS rather than a native `<button>`).

However, most of your question was about `tabindex`, which technically isn't an ARIA attribute.  Tabindex has been around for a long time.  The [doc on tabindex](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#the-tabindex-attribute) explains the 4 types of values:

- no value
- negative value
- 0 value
- positive value

I won't explain the differences unless you need it because in your case you should not need `tabindex` at all.  You don't want to make non-interactive elements keyboard focusable. You mentioned moving the focus to the header, footer, main, etc. None of those are interactive elements so they should not receive focus.

If your menu is using links (`<a>`) or buttons (`<button>`), then they will already be keyboard focusable with the <kbd>tab</kbd> key and `tabindex` won't be needed.

> when entering in document, that when I press TAB key, **it focuses on the tag** and when I press TAB again, it goes down into the header

I'm not sure what you mean by *"focuses on the tag"*.

In your screenshot, if real links are being used, then the "natural" tab order would be:

1. Accueil
2. Produits
3. Services
4. Contact
5. Découvir ce service
6. Découvir ce service
7. Découvir ce service

and you wouldn't need any extra code for it to work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Actually, I've always been used to use semantic HTML so as for this part, it's done.
The thing is that as you said last, indeed when using TAB key, it focuses in the right order of the nav elements then focuses on the links in the cards.

The thing I'm struggling to imagine how does it works is to read the content of the page, the one not interactible with.

You said " You don't want to make non-interactive elements keyboard focusable ".
Well that's what I'm wondering : how the blind user will be able to tab on text to read it so ?

Comment: That's a common question if you're not familiar with how screen readers work. There are many shortcut keys that allow a screen reader user to navigate the page and get to all the text, especially if you're already using semantic html. For example, the `H` key will navigate to the next heading, assuming you used `<h1>`, `<h2>`, etc for your headings (or `role="heading" aria-level="2"`). The `L` will navigate to the next list if you used `<ul>`.  `T` will go to a table if you used `<table>`.  The up/down arrow keys will navigate to the next DOM element so all text is available to blind users.

Comment: Ok so I've tried up and down arrow and it works fine indeed. The thing is that when doing this, when you enter into a card, it doesn't tell you it's a card. It will only read text and interactible elements. Isn't there a way to tell the user you enter in a particular section/card/footer/etc... ?

Comment: That's where semantic elements come into play.  Group your card into a `<section aria-label="title for the card">`

Comment: oh ok, I see... I'll try with <article> also because I feel like section is more appropriate for some global big container than for a card, maybe I'm wrong and section is, as for accessibility, more appropriate for a card. Anyway, I'll study all of the semantic tags and aria-label.

Comment: Exactly.  Just use a semantic "grouping" element with an `aria-label`.  If your cards have a heading (eg, `<h3>`), it'll make it easy for a screen reader user to navigate to each card. If they don't have headings, then consider using an html element that is a landmark (https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#landmark_roles). A `<section>` is a "region" landmark. An `<article>` is not a landmark but that doesn't mean you shouldn't use it. See https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#el-a for the default role for each html element. You're on the right path.